# Detect background-color (hex) of element and compare to hex-spectrum

Tags: jquery, css

I want to detect the background-color (hex) of the element on top of the viewport and compare it to the spectrum of hex-codes (if the color is more on the #FFFFFF or #000000 side). I need this so I can change the color of the sticky header on top, which has a transparent background.

Is it possible to set a range of hex-codes (for example #000000 until #EFEFEF) so I can start an action when the detected color falls inside this range?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is relative luminescence. Have a look here to see if this can assist you with your problem:

- https://css-tricks.com/switch-font-color-for-different-backgrounds-with-css/

However, I am not sure that using such harsh colours is the right solution in the first place. If you have a dark menu then change the opacity to be semi-transparent with a light text. If you have a light menu then set the text to be lighter. See the below fiddle for an example.

- https://jsfiddle.net/nvLbro8z/2/

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#a {
  background: red;
}

#b {
  background: purple;
}

#c {
  background: yellow;
}

#d {
  background: green;
}

#e {
  background: blue;
}

#f {
  background: black;
}

#g {
  height: 100vh;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#option-a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: white;
}

#option-b {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="option-a">
    This is the menu option A
  </div>
  <div id="option-b">
    This is the menu option B
  </div>
</div>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
```